# In NextJs@13, setState is not working in form action

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, app-router

I made a contact form like below with Next13.5, app router.
But setIsLoading in the try-catch doesn’t work well. It fires at the same time as the server action response returns.
The server action is simple email sending and it is sendEmail() at the code.

Does anyone know what happens at the form action?
What I want to know is why the state update timing is delayed. sendEmail() is always working.

```js
"use client"
import { sendEmail } from '@/features/sendEmail'

export const Contact() => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  const formAction  = async () => {
    try {
        setIsLoading(true) // this fire at the same as end of sendEmail()
        const result = await sendEmail(formData) // this function is server action
        result.success ? router.push("thanks") : setError("server error")
      } catch (error) {
        setServerError(`${error}`)
        setIsLoading(false)
      }
    }
  return (
    <form action={formAction}>
      {/* some inputs */}
      <button type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>
        {isLoading ? 'sending' : 'send'}
      </button>
    </form>
  )
}
// ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations
```

I tried to rewrite it to onClick function like below at the submit button and that worked well.
isLoading was updated to true at the time the button was pressed, and it reverted to false after the email was sent.

```js
const submitFunc async () => {
  setIsLoading(true)
  const result = await sendEmail(formData) // this function is server action
  setIsLoading(false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'use client'
 
import { useFormStatus } from 'react-dom'
 
export function SubmitButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus()
 
  return (
    <button type="submit" aria-disabled={pending}>
      Add
    </button>
  )
}
```

This component needs to be nested in the form. Only this way it works.

In the future, you will be able to use `useActionState` outside (which replaces useFormState). See https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/28491

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution. I use useFormStatus() and loading works well.
I hope it helps anyone!

doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#displaying-loading-state

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).